# How to use large amounts of static text in a JSF application?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat, file-io

I am creating a JSF application which has alot of text to be displayed statically, Such as descriptions and details.

Now my problem is that i cant use the properties file since it takes line by line and i can have upto 100 lines in para straight.

Database also cannot be used for some business reason.

Pasting data directly within the value tag of the faces-config.xml file is an option i want to take if no other is possible

Now i thought of using a simple text file instead and populating my bean property directly using this within the class.

However i am having difficulty using this. Path is not coming out to be correct and some kind of overlapping in the bean property is occurring as well.

I am using Eclipse Helios and Tomcat for development. So please consider the directory structure to be the same as used by standard projects in Eclipse.

Can someone please provide a sample code or a process on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is storing the static text in a database an option? You could load it up in an @ApplicationScoped bean so it would be retrieved only once in your application. You could read the same from a text file as well but if you are already utilizing a database then this is how i would go.

Answer (score 0):

> Path is not coming out to be correct

You can use [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get an input stream to a file on the classpath. For example, if your text file is at `/WEB-INF/classes/foo.txt`, you can open it like this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/foo.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various options and they depend on how unique pages with such large amounts of static text are and how much other JSF components they contain.

One option is to simply create your pages in separate folders corresponding with the locales you support, and create versions for each locale. Then, if you are using Facelets, let those pages be template clients of a master template that contains your general website frame (top, bottom, etc).

This works well for pages that are mainly text based. You'll expose a separate URL for each language version. E.g. www.example.com/en/my_page.xhtml en www.example.com/nl/my_page.xhtml, etc.

If those pages contain only a few components, you could include those via ui:include, but this can quickly become messy and pages for different locales may run out of sync. To combat that, you could define a template per page. This template can itself be a template client of the general master template and it contains all the components necessary for a specific page. The final client of this template then fills in the large amounts of static text.

In case you don't want to expose different URLs to the end user, you can also opt to include the large amount of static text dynamically. Consider the following simple Facelet:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
>       
    <h:body>    
        <ui:include src="#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}/text.xhtml" />     
    </h:body>
</html>
```

*(this is just a quick example, instead of #{facesContext.viewRoot.locale} you could also use a backing bean over which you might have a little more control)*